# What is the purpose of using the embed tag in html?

Tags: html

I want to know what's embed tag is used for?

from W3SCHOOL :

> The  tag defines a container for an external resource, such as a web page, a picture, a media player, or a plug-in application

I'm confused about **external resource**
I mean what is external resource?

Comment: Don't use this tag, it's not really needed anymore nowadays.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed), it may help you answer your question.

Comment: Awful though W3Schools is, it does give three examples before it gets to that description.

Comment: @Quentin what is external resource?

Comment: @Quentin how is it Awful?!!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: @Quentin very thanks. what is your suggestion as to the best replacement for it? for CSS-HTML-JAVASCRIPT

Comment: See the link deceze posted. Also the actual specs.

Answer (score 0):

The external resource is an address that you receive your media. e.g src of an image, a text HTML, a video, etc. But as said in : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp

**Suggestion**

- To display a picture, it is better to use the `<img>` tag.
- To display HTML, it is better to use the `<iframe>` tag.
- To display video or audio, it is better to use the `<video>` and `<audio>` tags.